# What is this Tree?

Tags: botany, species-identification

What is this plant?

Location: Bangalore, India
[image: Fruit]
[image: Fruit]
[image]

Comment: Breadfruit. *Artocarpus incisus* . With several other synonymous scientific names. Family moraceae. Close-relative of Jackfruit (*Artocarpus heterophylla*)

Comment: This is a famous species, available in  English dictionaries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks very very suggestive for Artocarpus altilis or [Breadfruit tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadfruit).

Another variants -  [Artocarpus camansi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artocarpus_camansi).

[image]

Comment: How on earth do you manage to do this.... +1 :)

Comment: @AliceD Thanks, this tree has very special influence in design history, so the task was easily solvable. Learn more about it http://www.ctahr.hawaii.edu/oc/freepubs/pdf/breadfruit.pdf

Comment: Thanks Ilan for providing us with this info. What a beautiful tree. I like the cool leaves and fruits. Never tasted one though.